# Convert Database string which is in .DOC format to .DOCX format on the fly

Tags: string, .doc

I have retrieved a string which was in Byte array. I converted the byte array to string.
`byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(entity.Attributes["body"].ToString());
            string bodyContent = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(binary);`
The string can be saved as a .DOC file. But my objective is to use open XML. For that i need to Convert the file to .DOCX.without saving the file can i convert the file to .DOCX.

Comment: How would you expect that conversion (from a binary .DOC format to an XML-based .DOCX format) to happen? Magic? Byte fairies? How would you expect that transformation to be done?

Comment: Now I am storing the file in local and using interop to save to docX. is there any other approach as it is taking lots of time